# Highcharts.SVGRenderer not working properly with Drill Down

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, drilldown

I have a Highcharts column graph in my application and it has a drill down behavior. Initially, it shows the Yearly wise count of something and then upon clicking on a year it shows the monthly view of that Year. Also, that Monthly View shows from December to Last Year December so that I have another requirement like need to separate two years. This Year wise separation should come in monthly view only. Something similar to the following image. But the problem is If I call the Separator adding method inside Drilldown event on Highcharts it doesn't add the separator as intended. What I want is something like following.

[image: Yearly View]

If I click on 2018 graph should be something like following.

[image: Monthly View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use drilldown event only to save the right year in the chart:

```
function renderSeparator(xVal, chart, year) {
  var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
    pxVal = xAxis.toPixels(xVal + 0.5);

  chart.additionalLabels.push(chart.renderer.path([
    'M', pxVal, chart.plotTop,
    'L', pxVal, chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight
  ]).attr({
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
  }).add());

  chart.additionalLabels.push(chart.renderer.text(
    year, pxVal + 10, 70
  ).css({
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 20
  }).attr({
    zIndex: 6
  }).add());
}

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {

        e.target.drilldownYear = e.point.name;
      },
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
          additionalLabels,
          year = Number(chart.drilldownYear);

        if (!chart.additionalLabels) {
          chart.additionalLabels = [];
        }

        if (chart.additionalLabels.length) {
          Highcharts.each(chart.additionalLabels, function(label) {
            label.destroy();
          });
          chart.additionalLabels = [];
        }

        Highcharts.each(xAxis.names, function(el, i) {
          if (el === "December") {

            if (!chart.additionalLabels.length) {
              chart.additionalLabels.push(chart.renderer.text(year, chart.plotLeft + 10, 70)
                .css({
                  color: 'black',
                  fontSize: 20
                })
                .attr({
                  zIndex: 6
                })
                .add());

              year++;
            }

            renderSeparator(i, chart, year);
            year++;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    type: 'column'
  },

  ...

});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qtr5x1po/

Similar topic: [Add Custom Labels to Axes in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291860/add-custom-labels-to-axes-in-highcharts/52295690?noredirect=1#comment91561101_52295690)

Comment: Thanks it worked